# Invalid Datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE table flight_details(
flight_id char(10),
flight_date date,
flight_time time,
flight_place varchar2(50),
tp_id char(8),
primary key (flight_id),
foreign key (tp_id) references travel_package(tp_id));
```

when i execute this 
this error appear

`flight_time time,
            *
ERROR at line 4: 
ORA-00902: invalid datatype`

How to solve this?

Comment: What does _line 4_ contain?

Comment: Oracle RDBMS doesn't have a `time` [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm). Why would you want to store date and time in separate columns?

Comment: There is no time data type in Oracle. Please consider uniting the flight_date and flight_time into one date column.

Comment: got any data type can be use and store the time only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timestamp` instead of `time`

```
CREATE table flight_details(
flight_id char(10),
flight_date date,
flight_time timestamp,
flight_place varchar2(50),
tp_id char(8),
primary key (flight_id),
foreign key (tp_id) references travel_package(tp_id));
```

Comment: Timestamp also contains the date, and it's unlikely you'd want fractional-seconds precision for a flight time; if you really wanted to store the time and date separately (which you probably don't) then timestamp doesn't seem like a great fit for the time-only part.

Comment: @AlexPoole yup that's write. but op was giving time as a datatype which is not present so I just provide with optional datatype which will store time as well

Answer (score 0):

Use interval day(0) to second instead of time data type for flight_time column. 
and refer this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42084/most-efficient-and-practical-way-to-store-time-values-hhmm-in-oracle-that-mak